# mysql_num_rows() not working at all

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of PHP code:

```
<?php
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

if($username&&$password){
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(" Couldnt connect");
mysql_select_db("phplogin") or die ("Can't find database" .mysql_error());  
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * users WHERE username='$username' ");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if (!$query) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
}
else
die ("Enter username and password!") .mysql_error();
?>
```

However, when I try to run this code I get these errors:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\PHP testing\login.php on line 9

and

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'users WHERE username='alex'' at line 1

Can someone explain to me what I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: -1 for posting SQL-injectable code

Comment: ^Johan he(Mentalhead) is here on SO to learn by mistakes so you can comment your view without -1.

Comment: @Johan if he knew what are you writing about he wouldn't ask about... `mysql_num_rows()` :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify a table from which you're selecting with FROM keyword:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' ");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: You're right, I completely missed the FROM keyword, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

you should really check for errors after your query, then the system will tell you what is wrong

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * users WHERE username='$username' ");

if (mysql_error() {
   die(mysql_error());
}

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

as @mike commented, your select query is missing the from bit

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' "
```

Answer (score 4):

Well Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql%20injection) Attack

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

instead of above use this code 

$username= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Comment: I know it's vulnerable, it's just for testing and learning purposes, but thanks for this security tip.

Answer (score 1):

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db("phplogin") or die("Couldn't find db");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin", $connect);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

and it will evaluate resource

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * users WHERE username='$username' ");
if (mysql_error() {
   die(mysql_error());
}
$numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $numberOfRows;
```